# What is the recursive approach for printing the longest common substring in C

Tags: c

Please help I want a recursive approach for printing the longest common substring not the length but the strings between two strings in C. This is what I have tried and it returns the length but I want an actual string to be printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define max(x,y) (((x) >= (y)) ? (x) : (y))
#define min(x,y) (((x) <= (y)) ? (x) : (y))

int LCS(char *s1, char  *s2, int m, int n, int lcsCount){
    int lcsCount1 = 0;
    lcsCount1 = lcsCount;
    if(m <= 0 || n <= 0){
        return lcsCount;

    }if(s1[m - 1] == s2[n - 1]){
        lcsCount1 = LCS(s1, s2, m-1, n-1, lcsCount + 1);
    }

    int lcsCount2 = LCS(s1, s2, m, n-1, 0);
    int lcsCount3 = LCS(s1, s2, m-1, n, 0);

    return max(lcsCount1, max(lcsCount2, lcsCount3));
}

int main()
{
    char X[500] = "Sandile";
    char Y[500] = "andile";

    int m = strlen(X);
    int n = strlen(Y);

    int result = LCS(X, Y, m, n, 0);
    printf("%d", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to save the strings'index where your find the first same char.

Then, at the end of the program, as you know where the first char occurs and the length of substring, you just have to print it.